# SQL Server : Sum function is returning wrong value

Tags: sql-server, join

So this is my query

```
   select a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID,c.ersGeographyDimension_country,
   b.ERSTimeDimension_Year,
  sum(a.ERSDataValues_AttributeValue) as Total
  from cosd.ERSDataValues a ,cosd.ERSTimeDimension_LU 
 b,cosd.ERSGeographyDimension_LU c
where   a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID  in (SELECT 
ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries
FROM [AnimalProductsCoSD].[CoSD].[ERSBusinessLogic]
where ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID = 7493
and ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue = 'all months'
 and ERSBusinessLogic_Type = 'time aggregate')
 and a.ERSDataValues_ERSTimeDimension_ID = b.ERSTimeDimension_ID
and c.ersGeographyDimension_country != 'WORLD'
and a.ERSDataValues_ERSGeography_ID=c.ERSGeographyDimension_ID
group by b.ERSTimeDimension_Year,a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID,
c.ersGeographyDimension_country
order by b.ERSTimeDimension_Year,a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID
```

This is the updated query, I know it is long but I am facing the same issue the sum does not match with values when I sum up manually

Comment: Perhaps sample data and expected results would be helpful.  I'm not seeing how you are `joining` to your `geographydimension` table.  I'd highly recommend using `explicit` joins with an `on` clause instead of using commas in your `from` clause.

Comment: What defines a unique row in the join between these tables?

Comment: You're probably adding wrong when you do it manually.

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a problem with your JOINs (which you aren't technically using). Try removing the SUM and GROUP functions and see if you're getting duplicate rows (maybe limit your time frame to get fewer rows if this is a large data set):

```
SELECT  b.TimeDimension_Year ,
        c.GeographyDimension_country ,
        a.DataValues_AttributeValue
FROM    cosd.DataValues a ,
        cosd.TimeDimension_LU b ,
        cosd.GeographyDimension_LU c
WHERE   a.DataValues_Commodity_ID = 2257
        AND a.DataValues_TimeDimension_ID = b.TimeDimension_ID
        AND c.GeographyDimension_ID = 7493
        AND b.TimeDimension_Year = 2015;
```

Comment: This gives me completely different output and sum value is changing too.

Comment: It's supposed to give different output: you're looking for duplicate lines that are throwing off your SUM. For example, if there are duplicate items in GeographyDimension you'll get two copies of a DataValue record, one for each Geo. This is not a solution, it's just a way to find out where the problem is. :)